# Audio Feature Extraction in Java using musicg

Tags: java, signal-processing

I am trying to extract features of an audio signal in my project. Is there any jar in java that helps me in extracting features.

Answer (score 0):

Have you done your research? It this what you are looking for?: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/capturing.html

Comment: I have already captured the audio. Now i want to extract its features for example Length, Type, SampleRate, FrameRate etc.